# Swift generics causing trouble in parser combinator code

Tags: swift

I am writing code for a parser combinator system in Swift as an exercise in understanding them, but I'm continually running into trouble with generics in Swift, perhaps because I do not fully understand them. I will describe the error, but first, some background. In my code, a `Parser` is just a type alias:

`typealias Parser<T> = (String) -> (output: [T], remainder: String)?`

In essence, a parser takes input and then returns either:

1. a tuple with an array of output items and the unparsed remainder of the input, or
2. `nil` if the parsing fails on the given input.

The code that demonstrates my problem is as follows:

```
struct Op {

}

func lineOfCode() -> Parser<Op> {
    return { input in
        return nil
    }
}

func program() -> Parser<Op> {
    return { input in
        return anyNumber(of: lineOfCode())
    }
}
```

Right now, there is a bit of do-nothing code, but the problem lies in the `return` statement of the parser generated by the `program()` method. It displays the following error:

`Cannot convert call result type '(String) -> (output: [_], remainder: String)?' to expected type '(output: [Op], remainder: String)?'`

For completeness, the `anyNumber(of:)` method is a parser generator that yields a parser which is effectively 0...* of the input parser. Its signature is:

```
anyNumber<T>(of parser: @escaping Parser<T>) -> Parser<T>
```

I greatly appreciate any insight on my very specific issue, as this error is very cryptic to me and I can't find out what I am supposed to make of it, namely this "underscore type" which is mysterious to me.

Comment: Just at a glance it would appear that `anyNumber`, being generic, is requiring a bit more specification as to what sort of Array it will be returning. That's what `output: [_]` seems to be hinting at. Is there a way to write `anyNumber<Op>`?

Comment: @sdasdadas Swift is unfortunately not Java and you can't explicitly specify generic type parameters when calling a method. Every parameters must be inferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expanded the code in `program` and found the root of the problem:

```
func program() -> Parser<Op> {
    return { input in
        let anyNum = anyNumber(of: lineOfCode())
        return anyNum
    }
}
```

The error now says:

> cannot convert return expression of type '(String) -> (output: [Op], remainder: String)?' to return type '(output: [Op], remainder: String)?'

It's much clearer now isn't it!

`anyNumber` returns a `Parser<T>`. You want to return the return value of `anyNumber` in a closure. This closure's return type however, is not `Parser<T>`. It is `(output: [Op], remainder: String)?`. Type mismatch!

I think you want to do this instead?

```
func program() -> Parser<Op> {
    return anyNumber(of: lineOfCode())
}
```

Comment: Yep! It appears as though I was implementing a parser-generator-generator rather than a parser-generator. That closure shorthand seems to disappear if you're not looking closely!